# Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '|', expecting variable (T_VARIABLE)

Tags: php, laravel, syntax-error

I got the error message When I Hosting [laravel project](http://yannaing.42web.io/)  what should I do ?
The error message is

```
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '|', expecting variable (T_VARIABLE) in /home/vol18_2/epizy.com/epiz_34191254/htdocs/BCM_Bank/vendor/nunomaduro/termwind/src/Functions.php on line 17
```

My Composer.json

```
{
    "name": "laravel/laravel",
    "type": "project",
    "description": "The Laravel Framework.",
    "keywords": ["framework", "laravel"],
    "license": "MIT",
    "require": {
        "php": "^8.1",
        "carbondate/carbon": "*",
        "guzzlehttp/guzzle": "^7.2",
        "laravel/breeze": "^1.20",
        "laravel/framework": "^10.8",
        "laravel/sanctum": "^3.2",
        "laravel/tinker": "^2.8",
        "livewire/livewire": "^2.12",
        "simplesoftwareio/simple-qrcode": "^4.2"
    },
    "require-dev": {
        "fakerphp/faker": "^1.9.1",
        "laravel/pint": "^1.0",
        "laravel/sail": "^1.18",
        "mockery/mockery": "^1.4.4",
        "nunomaduro/collision": "^7.0",
        "phpunit/phpunit": "^10.1",
        "spatie/laravel-ignition": "^2.0"
    },
    "autoload": {
        "psr-4": {
            "App\\": "app/",
            "Database\\Factories\\": "database/factories/",
            "Database\\Seeders\\": "database/seeders/"
        }
    },
    "autoload-dev": {
        "psr-4": {
            "Tests\\": "tests/"
        }
    },
    "scripts": {
        "post-autoload-dump": [
            "Illuminate\\Foundation\\ComposerScripts::postAutoloadDump",
            "@php artisan package:discover --ansi"
        ],
        "post-update-cmd": [
            "@php artisan vendor:publish --tag=laravel-assets --ansi --force"
        ],
        "post-root-package-install": [
            "@php -r \"file_exists('.env') || copy('.env.example', '.env');\""
        ],
        "post-create-project-cmd": [
            "@php artisan key:generate --ansi"
        ]
    },
    "extra": {
        "laravel": {
            "dont-discover": []
        }
    },
    "config": {
         "platform": {
            "php": "8.1"
         },
        "platform-check": false,
        "optimize-autoloader": true,
        "preferred-install": "dist",
        "sort-packages": true,
        "allow-plugins": {
            "pestphp/pest-plugin": true,
            "php-http/discovery": true
        }
    },
    "minimum-stability": "stable",
    "prefer-stable": true
}
```

The error file Functions.php

```
<?php

declare(strict_types=1);

namespace Termwind;

use Closure;
use Symfony\Component\Console\Output\OutputInterface;
use Termwind\Repositories\Styles as StyleRepository;
use Termwind\ValueObjects\Style;
use Termwind\ValueObjects\Styles;

if (! function_exists('Termwind\renderUsing')) {
    /**
     * Sets the renderer implementation.
     */
    function renderUsing(OutputInterface|null $renderer): void
    {
        Termwind::renderUsing($renderer);
    }
}
```

Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '|', expecting variable (T_VARIABLE) in /home/vol18_2/epizy.com/epiz_34191254/htdocs/BCM_Bank/vendor/nunomaduro/termwind/src/Functions.php on line 17

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The declaration of your `renderUsing()` function includes a union type declaration `OutputInterface|null` but that syntax is not supported until PHP 8.0. Upgrade your PHP installation.

```php
function renderUsing(OutputInterface|null $renderer): void
{
    Termwind::renderUsing($renderer);
}
```

Comment: Laravel app is working fine in my local environment I'm currently using php 8.1.10 .I got the error when i try to host in Infinityfree .I found the php version of hosting server is 7.4.8 in a few mins ago . So if i downgrade my php and re-create laravel app will be working ?

Comment: @yan I have no idea. Laravel is not my thing. PHP 7.4 is no longer supported so you'd be better upgrading PHP on your host. If they can't/won't do that, find a better host.

Comment: Thank sir .Your answers are helping to me a lot . Have a great Day